# how to create measure that would divide monthly values by different dates?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have 2 different dates `Date Entered` and `Date Closed` in my table. 
Calendar table joined on `Date Entered` column.

I need to divide monthly value summed by `Date Entered` by monthly value summed  by `Date Closed` ?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Forgot about USERELATIONSHIP function:

First, I created not active relationship between `DateClosed` and `dim_Date`. 
Then created a measure:

```
    Claims by Closed Date = CALCULATE(
                             [Ttl Closed Claims],
             USERELATIONSHIP(fact_Loss[DateClosed],dim_Date[Date])
)
```